# How to handle a tapping on non-cell area of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableView` with a couple of `UITableViewCells` in it. Because I only have a couple of cells, there is an area of the table view that's not covered by the cells. And I want to do something when the empty area is tapped.

I tried adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the table view. It detects the tapping on the empty area, but then the cells fail to respond to tapping. I tried adding the tap gesture recognizer on the super view of the table view, but the result is the same.

There must be a way to do this, but I can't quite figure it out yet. Is there any way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to detect taps on the empty area?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add buttons under a tableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178498/add-buttons-under-a-tableview)

Comment: @sha, I have a text field in one of the cells. During editing on the text field, if the user taps on the empty area, I want to get out of the editing mode.

Comment: @carl this is not duplicate because I'm not talking about adding buttons under the table view.

Comment: @Jake The questions are different and that's OK, but the solution possibly is the same - that is, use a table footer view of the size of the empty space - did you try that and that didn't work?

Comment: @CarlVeazey I didn't try the button idea, but I can imagine it would work too. I just used the gesture delegate solution suggested below and it's working great for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:
initialize and add the UITapGestureRecognizer to your tableView:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
gr.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
gr.delegate = self;
[_tableView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

implement the gesture recognizer delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    CGPoint tapPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:_tableView];
    UIView * clickedView = [_tableView hitTest:tapPoint withEvent:nil];
    NSString *viewClassName = NSStringFromClass(clickedView.class);
    return ![viewClassName hasPrefix:@"UITableViewCell"];
}
```

this way every tap you do outsude cells (but inside the tableview) will be recognized with your `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: I am using custom UITableViewCells iOS 8 and the class name for me is "UITableViewCellContentView"

Answer (score 0):

The last line: `return ![viewClassName hasPrefix:@"UITableViewCell"];`
should be changed to `return [viewClassName hasPrefix:@"UITableView"];` since the cell you are clicking doesn't have to be a UITableViewCell, but a UIView or some other custom view